# WordPress insert_post

Tags: wordpress

Написал функцию вставку постов, но почему-то не работает.

```
function insertPost($title, $content, $status, $category = '')
{
    $postData = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $content,
        'post_status' => $status,
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_category' => array( 8,39 )
    );
    return wp_insert_post(wp_slash($postData));
}
```

Раньше таким образом удавалось вставлять, сейчас какая-то беда.

Лог ВП:

```
[18-Nov-2020 12:12:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'feeds' of non-object in /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 4482
[18-Nov-2020 12:12:01 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'use_trailing_slashes' of non-object in /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/link-template.php on line 49
[18-Nov-2020 12:12:01 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php:2611
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(6994): _count_posts_cache_key('post', 'readable')
#1 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): _transition_post_status('origin', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#2 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#3 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4813): do_action('transition_post...', 'origin', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#5 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php(4160): wp_transition_post_status('origin', 'new', Object(WP_Post))
#6 /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-content/plugins/T2W/includes/class-plugin-name-loader.php(153): wp_insert_post(Array)
#7 /storage/ssd1/253/1532 in /storage/ssd1/253/15325253/public_html/wp-includes/post.php on line 2611
```

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/id_7791/debag-v-wordpress-wp_debug.html

Comment: Без сообщений об ошибках и распечатки значений передаваемых переменных тут можно долго гадать.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, докинул логи. Интересная трабла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция не определена, потому что ядро не закончило загрузку. Вы слишком рано пытаетесь вызвать `wp_insert_post`. Файл `pluggable.php`, в котором находится `is_user_logged_in`, подключается сразу после загрузки всех плагинов, после чего срабатывает событие `plugins_loaded`.

Повесьте свой код на хук `plugins_loaded` или `init` (который срабатывает ещё позже), как положено, и не пытайтесь его выполнить прямо в файле плагина.